How can show division of fraction with tikz?
How can get the arrows as shown in the picture with Tikz? Thank you in advance.
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
        \frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{c}{d}}=\frac{ad}{bc}
    \end{equation*}
    \end{document}



Please show what you tried and how far you got yourself.

I do not know more about tikz. I searched for it but did not get the same tikz arrows. I would be grateful if you can help me.

Even if you don't know tikz, you could try to write the math equation. You can also do all the boring work like write \documentclass etc. That's nothing which requires knowledge of tikz.

I edited the question and added the minimal working sheet.

Do you want the curly brackets, too? In TikZ?

yes please curly brackets and the arrow with them. I mean it should same as in the picture

Using tikzmark and brace decorations.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \frac{\quad\dfrac{\tikzmarknode{A}{a}}{{}\tikzmarknode{B}{b}}\quad}{\dfrac{{}\tikzmarknode{C}{c}}{\tikzmarknode{D}{d}}}=\frac{\tikzmarknode{AD}{ad}}{{}\tikzmarknode{BC}{bc}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, aspect=.25}](A.east)--coordinate[pos=.25](R)(D.east);
    \draw[decorate, decoration={brace, aspect=.25}](C.west)--coordinate[pos=.25](S)(B.west);
    \draw[->]([xshift=2pt]R)--(AD);
    \draw[->, looseness=2.2]([xshift=-2pt]S)to[out=240,in=225](BC);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Why is the bracket uneven? Is that deliberate?

@Simd: Yes, it's intentional. I did it so the point would be away from the fraction line. You can control the position of the "middle part" with aspect=<percentage>. This will place the pointy part of the brace at <percentage> from the start of the path.

With nicematrix and tikz:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
  $\begin{NiceArray}[name = frac1]{ccc}
    ~ & a & ~\\ \cline{2}
      & b &  \\ \hline
      & c &  \\ \cline{2}
      & d &
  \end{NiceArray} = \begin{NiceArray}[name = frac2]{cc}
  ad\\ \hline bc
\end{NiceArray}$
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay, shorten <=1mm]
  \draw [->] (frac1-1-2) to[out=0, in=135] (frac2-1-1) ;
  \draw [->] (frac1-2-2) to[out=0, in=180] (frac2-2-1) ;
  \draw [->] (frac1-3-2) to[out=0, in=-50] (frac2-2-1) ;
  \draw [->] (frac1-4-2) to[out=0, in=-30, looseness=2.5] (frac2-1-1) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



You could use tikzmarks. To give you a starting point:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \frac{\frac{a}{b}}{\frac{\tikzmark{foo}c}{d}}=\frac{ad}{b\tikzmark{bar}c}
\end{equation*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->] (pic cs:foo) to[in=270,out=220,looseness=2.5] (pic cs:bar);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Resources which will help you to add the rest yourself:

TikZ User Manual: General TikZ stuff, has a tutorial at the start
tikzmarks documentation: specific information about \tikzmark etc.


Please can you add the curly brackets and the arrows with them as shown in the picture?

@SamiaRani You can add them with the same technique. Look into the tikz user guide for examples with decorate,decoration=brace
